# springboot has "failed to start tomcat" error with spring-data-hadoop dependency added

Tags: java, spring, maven, hadoop, spring-boot

i got this error when i tried to build SpringBoot + Hadoop project as my portfolio.

here is my programs version description.

hadoop version = 2.7.3, spring-data-hadoop dependency version = 2.5.0,springboot version = 2.0.0.Release

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/Logan/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/Logan/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-api.jar,file:/Users/Logan/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/activation.jar,file:/Users/Logan/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jsr173_1.0_api.jar,file:/Users/Logan/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb1-impl.jar
01:35:31.800 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
01:35:31.803 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
01:35:31.803 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/Users/Logan/Documents/neon_workspace/springboot/portfolio/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-05-08 01:35:32.221  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] com.logan.Portfolio1Application          : Starting Portfolio1Application on LoganLeeui-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 38423 (/Users/Logan/Documents/neon_workspace/springboot/portfolio/target/classes started by Logan in /Users/Logan/Documents/neon_workspace/springboot/portfolio)
2018-05-08 01:35:32.223  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] com.logan.Portfolio1Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-08 01:35:32.482  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@63339078: startup date [Tue May 08 01:35:32 KST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-08 01:35:33.643  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-05-08 01:35:33.946  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$acd136bc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-05-08 01:35:34.437  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-05-08 01:35:34.460  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-08 01:35:34.460  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-05-08 01:35:34.464  INFO 38423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/Logan/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-05-08 01:35:34.569 ERROR 38423 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1186) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-05-08 01:35:34.573 ERROR 38423 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:417) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:176) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.logan.Portfolio1Application.main(Portfolio1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-05-08 01:35:34.575  WARN 38423 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-05-08 01:35:34.592  INFO 38423 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-08 01:35:34.608 ERROR 38423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.logan.Portfolio1Application.main(Portfolio1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:417) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

this error only come out when i added spring-data-hadoop dependency on pom.xml

also it worked fine without that dependency.

how can i fix this error?

Comment: the problem was version of servlet.
thus i added servlet dependency with new version.

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

then solved

Comment: From what i could see from the stack trace , this issue seems to be same as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675075/spring-bootrun-throws-error-when-add-hadoop-dependency